# Cannot GET page in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to open a new file when someone clicks on the "Lets edit stuff" button but I get the error Cannot GET /edit.ejs

Both of these files are in the same folder off views/pages/ but I keep getting this error. I have the server.js file running from node.

```
<body class="container">
    <main>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Homepage</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="edit.ejs">Lets edit stuff</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

This is what I see on the page

```
Cannot GET /edit.ejs
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was I did not have a app.get for edit so I had to add

```
app.get('/edit', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/edit');
});
```

in my server.js file